# Нужна помощь не знаю как это описать

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытаюсь помочь человеку сделать пианинко. Меня попросили, при возможности, максимально сократить код. Вроде все получилось,но столкнулся с проблемой:

Окно пианинки есть и хотелось бы клавиши с клавиатурой связать. Взял библиотеку msvcrt.getch() для отслеживания нажатий на клавиатуре, проблема в том, что когда окно открывается, не начнется отслеживание нажатий до момента, пока оно не закроется. А если вставить код с отслеживанием в код с пианино, то пока не закроется цикл отслеживания, не запустится окно. Я пробовал многопоточность ну или мультипроцессинг, но все равно не работает. Когда окно (с пианино) свернуто, то звук идет и музыка играет (когда нажимаешь клавиши на клавиатуре), а если открыть его, то тут же прекращается отслеживание.

сам программирую на python 1,5 года так что если что-то заметите, то подскажите как это исправить

вот код

```py
#all import's
import tkinter 
from tkinter import *
import winsound
import pygame
import msvcrt
import pygame
import keyboard

#init's with main frame
pygame.mixer.init()

not_red = Tk() 
not_red.resizable(0,0) 
not_red.configure(background = 'white') 
not_red.title('Piano') 
not_red.geometry('1253x221')

#1block

#-------------------------------------------|

#do cmd buttons

#play button
frame_play = Frame(not_red, bg = 'black', bd = 1)
frame_play.place(x = 10, y = 10)

play_btn = Button(frame_play, text = "►", bg = "#EAEAEA", fg = "black", font="15")
play_btn.pack()

#pause button
frame_pause = Frame(not_red, bg = 'black', bd = 1)
frame_pause.place(x = 50, y = 10)

pause_btn = Button(frame_pause, text = "▌▌", bg = "#EAEAEA", fg = "black", font="14")
pause_btn.pack()

#record button
frame_record = Frame(not_red, bg = 'black', bd = 1)
frame_record.place(x = 122, y = 10)

record_btn = Button(frame_record, text = "⚫", bg = "#EAEAEA", fg = "black", font="15")
record_btn.pack()

#-------------------------------------------|
#2block
#-------------------------------------------|

#function's to do white button's

def do_white_buttons(frame,count):
    for i in range(0,count):
        white_button = Button(frame, text = '', bg = 'white', fg = 'white', height = 10,width = 2)
        white_button.pack(side = LEFT)


frame = Frame(not_red, bg = 'black', bd = 3)
frame.place(x = 0, y = 55) 

#-------------------------------------------|
#3block
#-------------------------------------------|

def do_one_black_button(frame,size_x):
    '''To do 1 black button in begining'''
    black_button = Button(frame,text = '',bg = 'black',fg = 'white',height = 6,width = 1)
    black_button.place(x = size_x,y = 58)

def do_two_black_buttons(frame,size_x):
    '''To do 2 black button's'''
    for i in range(2):
        black_button = Button(frame,text = '',bg = 'black',fg = 'white',height = 6,width = 1)
        black_button.place(x = size_x,y = 58)
        size_x+=24

def do_three_black_buttons(frame,size_x):
    '''To do 3 black button's'''
    for i in range(3):
        black_button = Button(frame,text = '',bg = 'black', fg  = 'white',height = 6,width = 1)
        black_button.place(x = size_x,y = 58)
        size_x+=24

#-------------------------------------------|
#4block
#-------------------------------------------|

#coordinates for black button's

size_of_x_for_all_bbuttons = [65,137,233,305,401,473,569,641,
737,809,905,977,1073,1145]

#-------------------------------------------|
#5block
#-------------------------------------------|

#call all function's todo

#white
do_white_buttons(frame,52)

#black
do_one_black_button(not_red,18)

for i in range(1,len(size_of_x_for_all_bbuttons)):
    do_two_black_buttons(not_red,size_of_x_for_all_bbuttons[i-1])
    do_three_black_buttons(not_red,size_of_x_for_all_bbuttons[i])

#-------------------------------------------|

#MAINLOOP

not_red.mainloop()

#MAINLOOP FOR BUTTONS

run =  True
while run:
        if msvcrt.getch() == b'q':
                pygame.mixer.music.load('white_sounds\\white_0.wav')
```

простите за мой английский

Comment: Зачем вам консольный getch если вы используете GUI? Обрабатывайте события нажатия клавиши в окне.

Comment: в имеете ввиду bind то прикол в том что он здесь не работает, я запихиваю лямбда функцию в бинд а кнопки создаются в цикле и выходит так что кнопки еще не нажались а музыка уже начала играть и ну это такое себе